# Pass mut reference to a function, and get it back

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I try to write a code sample since an hour, who add some spaces in a `String`. So the main borrow a String to a function who add spaces, and then ,I wanna get the string back in the main function.

```rust
fn main() {
    ...
    let mut line = String::new();
    line = make_spaces(5, &mut line);
}

fn make_spaces(number: u8, string: &mut String) -> &mut String {
    for _ in 0..number {
        string.push(' ');
    }
    string
}
```

But the borrow checker give me the following error :

```sh
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:12
   |
14 |     line = make_spaces(left_spaces, &mut line);
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |            |
   |            expected struct `String`, found `&mut String`
   |            help: try using a conversion method: `make_spaces(left_spaces, &mut line).to_string()`
```

---

I'm new with `rust`, and I know I don't understand borrowing. But I searched the net, and I don't understand it any better.

As I understand, I give the `line` ownership to `make_spaces` function, and then I (try to) give the ownership of `string` back to the `main` function.

---

Could you tell me where I'm wrong what is the solution of this problem please ? I know it's a common issue, but I don't see anything simple about that on stackoverflow.

Comment: Why would you return a reference ? A more useful pattern is to return nothing. There's no need: the caller already has the modified struct.

Comment: Your function returns a `mutable reference to string`, but the type of `line` is `mutable String`. So you are trying to assign an incorrect type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to do what you're trying, but you're mixing the two:

## Take a mutable parameter as a reference

```
fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    make_spaces(5, &mut line);
}

fn make_spaces(number: u8, string: &mut String) {
    for _ in 0..number {
        string.push(' ');
    }
}
```

In that case, the caller gives you a reference to a struct so that you can modify it in place. There is no need to return anything.

## Move the parameter into the function, then return the modified value

```
fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    line = make_spaces(5, line);
}

fn make_spaces(number: u8, mut string: String) -> String {
    for _ in 0..number {
        string.push(' ');
    }
    string
}
```

In that case, the string is moved into the `make_spaces` function, so you need to move it back to the caller by returning it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. But the returned string is copy, right ?

Comment: Note that in Rust, when we say that "something is copy" we mean that it implements the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait, which `String` doesn't.

Comment: Assuming you were really asking if the string data is copied when it is returned, the answer is no: `String` is a struct that contains a pointer to the string data on the heap, that pointer is indeed copied but the data itself isn't (nor when it is passed as a parameter btw).

Comment: The `mut` in the `make_spaces` definition in the second case is misplaced. It will be before the variable name as `mut string: String`. Without this fix, the compiler throw an error.

Comment: what is the preferred approach in Rust?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to return anything: you received a reference to a struct the caller of the function already has.

Just do

```
fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    make_spaces(5, &mut line);
    // use line here
}

fn make_spaces(number: u8, string: &mut String) {
    for _ in 0..number {
        string.push(' ');
    }
}
```