# How to both modify and return self from method?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct and respective implementation:

```
pub struct Departments {
    pub id: String,
    pub linked_accounts: Vec<Account>,
}

impl Departments {
    pub fn add_account(&mut self, acct: Account) -> Self {
        let mut vec: Vec<Account> = self.linked_accounts;
        vec.push(acct);

        Self {
            id: self.id,
            linked_accounts: vec,
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.linked_accounts` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:10:37
   |
10 |         let mut vec: Vec<Account> = self.linked_accounts;
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.linked_accounts` has type `Vec<Account>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
10 |         let mut vec: Vec<Account> = &self.linked_accounts;
   |                                     +

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.id` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:14:17
   |
14 |             id: self.id, //*Error here*
   |                 ^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.id` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I use it when loading the department from the DB, adding account, and storing it back to the DB:

```
match db.get::<Departments>(id).await? {
    None => bail!("No records found"),
    Some(departments) => {
        let mut departments = departments;

        departments.add_account(Account::Credit);

        let id = Id::new(Departments::KIND, &id);
        gh.update::<_, Departments>(id, departments.clone()).await?;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is probably a XY problem. Anyway, we need more details.

Comment: I need to append a vector 'Account' value inside struct 'Departments', which is very straight forward..i am calling as 'dept.add_account(Account::EnumVal)' where Account as enum

Comment: I meant more details for why you specifically need to call with `&mut self` and return an owned `Self`.

Comment: main goal is not to pass the ownership from calling area, where i might need to assign a new variable, so i am passing as '&mut self'

Comment: Please provide more context. An example of the calling code will be good.

Comment: Added calling code as well,Note that Account is a Enum

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021274/pass-mut-reference-to-a-function-and-get-it-back/68021536#68021536

Comment: if you refer to add 'mut', i tried that as well. but No luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to interpret your question. In all the cases, the answer starts with *"Your function signature is wrong"*, but what exactly it should be, depends on your usecase.

But most certainly, it should be one of:

- `pub fn add_account(&mut self, acct: Account)`
- `pub fn add_account(&mut self, acct: Account) -> &mut Self`
- `pub fn add_account(mut self, acct: Account) -> Self`

I think the biggest misconception you are having is that you think you need to return `Self`. The way you are using `add_account`, by simply calling it on `departments.add_account(Account::Credit)` does **not** require you to return `Self`. You can directly modify the `self` object:

```rust
pub struct Departments {
    pub id: String,
    pub linked_accounts: Vec<Account>,
}

impl Departments {
    pub fn add_account(&mut self, acct: Account) {
        self.linked_accounts.push(acct);
    }
}
```

---

Now, there is a usecase where you want to return some form of `Self`, and that is if you want to be able to chain those calls:

```
departments
    .add_account(Account::Credit)
    .add_account(Account::Debit)
    .add_account(Account::Savings);
```

This is usually done by returning `&mut Self`:

```rust
pub struct Departments {
    pub id: String,
    pub linked_accounts: Vec<Account>,
}

impl Departments {
    pub fn add_account(&mut self, acct: Account) -> &mut Self {
        self.linked_accounts.push(acct);
        self
    }
}
```

Note that this *still* doesn't require you to instantiate a new `Self` object, like you were doing in your code.

---

### The actual error

In case you want to understand the original error:

- The `&mut self` argument means that you only borrow `self`, and you have to give it back at some point. (happens automatically at the end of the function)
- `let mut vec: Vec<Account> = self.linked_accounts;` *moves* the `linked_accounts` member *out* of `self`. This is only possible when we take ownership of `self` instead of borrowing it, because then, we can dismantle it to our pleasing. But as we need to give it back, we cannot just move members out of it.

I didn't talk about the actual error in more detail, because it was just an artifact of the incorrect function signature and didn't really contribute meaningfully to a solution.

Either way, I think there are a couple of misunderstandings of yours as to how ownership works, so I recommend reading the [ownership chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) of the Rust book.

The reason why I think you have misunderstandings, is because it is literally impossible to return `Self` if your function signature contains `&mut self`. `Self` is owned, and you cannot create an owned object from a borrowed one without copying it.

Yes, you are trying to create a copy of it in your attempt to implement it, but the usage example you posted shows me that you don't actually want to create a copy.

Comment: Thanks much, it works.. i will definitely read ur recommendations..

Answer (score 0):

In a meantime you can also `Clone` `Self`.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45c902d55a8f3e190893f82f720fdae2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).